# How can I make the figure's size bigger?

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to practice data visualization in IPython, but it seems the figure that I ploted is too small and I can't see it clearly.

So, could anyone give me any suggestion to solve this problem?

[image: d]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you constructed your figure manually, like `fig=plt.figure()` ?

Then you can add a size directly as a tuple of x,y in inches:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize = (5, 7))
```

Indeed, this is the idea behind explicitly constructing the figure. If you don't want to configure anything, you don't have to mention the figure at all, you can just do `plt.plot(...)`, and the figure arises automatically.